# How to open a new QDailog window when an element in the menu bar is clicked in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

Material class has a mainwindow with a menu bar. When i click one of the elements in the menu bar i want to open the Fiction Qdialog window.
material.h

```
#ifndef MATERIALS_H
#define MATERIALS_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "materialinner.h"
class FictionSection;

namespace Ui {
class Materials;
}

class Materials : public QMainWindow, public MaterialInner
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Materials(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Materials();

private:
    Ui::Materials *ui;
    FictionSection *fiction;
};

#endif // MATERIALS_H
```

materials.cpp

```
#include "materials.h"
#include "ui_materials.h"
#include "fictionsection.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

Materials::Materials(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Materials)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
 // connect(ui->ficti,SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),this,SLOT(displaySearch()));
}

Materials::~Materials()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Materials::on_actionFiction_section_triggered()
{
    this->hide();
     fiction = new FictionSection();
    fiction->show();

}
```

fictionsection.h

```
#ifndef FICTIONSECTION_H
#define FICTIONSECTION_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "materials.h"


namespace Ui {
class FictionSection;
}

class FictionSection : public QDialog, public Materials
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FictionSection(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FictionSection();

private:
    Ui::FictionSection *ui;

};

#endif // FICTIONSECTION_H
```

When i compile it gives an error which is
   **Request for member 'show' is ambiguous.** 
Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `FictionSection` class inherits from both `QDialog` and `Materials`, but your `Materials` class also inherits from `QMainWindow`. Both `QMainWindow` and `QDialog` have a virtual `show()` method (inherited from `QWidget`), which causes the ambiguity. In other words: do you intend to call `QMainWindow::show`'s implementation or `QDialog::show`'s implementation? No one knows.

To solve this, you should use inheritance properly. Inherit from either `QMainWindow` or `QDialog`, but *not both*.

You need to understand *why* it is that you're inheriting the way you are (which is wrong) and improve the logic of the relationship between your classes to avoid problems like this one.

Also, class names should be singular, so `Materials` should be `Material`. If it needs to handle multiple things, then it could be `MaterialManager` or something similar.

Comment: @user3279893 if it helps you, mark the answer "accepted" to make other people know the solution of this kind of problem.